# Date comparison result

Tags: c#

Why does the code below result in a (-1)?

When the startDate is set to *7/9/12 5:00:00 AM* the compareValue returns 1. I would expect a positive 1 in the scenario below but getting a (-1).

```
startDate = "7/16/2012 5:00:00 AM"
endDate = "7/17/2012 5:00:00 AM"

//enter code here
int compareValue =  startDate.CompareTo(endDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to compare `strings` here. If you compare using string '7/9/12 5:00:00 AM' you get a result of `1` because `'7/9/12 5:00:00 AM'` is lexicographically larger than `'7/17/2012 5:00:00 AM'`.

Comment: That makes sense, Thanks Tom - I tried using DateTime.Parse() and Convert.toDateTime but same result. I switched the comparTo to DateTime.Compare(startDate, endDate) and it seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

`-1` means that `startDate` is earlier than `endDate`, which is true in this case. According to [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x79949f0.aspx) `CompareTo` returns:

- < 0 instance is eariler than value
- == 0 instance is the same as value
- > 0 instance is later than value or value is null

Answer (score 0):

CompareTo method returns -1: 7/16/2012 5:00:00 AM is earlier than 7/1/2012 5:00:00 AM

```
Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/5ata5aya.aspx
```